# Meteor.user().profile.myProp reactive for all profile children

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client public method needs to re run when the `Meteor.user().profile.propA` changes which is does fine, but it also runs when `profile.propB` changes or added. How can I stop it from re running when **any other** child property of `profile` has changed or added but only for `profile.propA`? Thanks

```
    myListener: () => {
      Tracker.autorun(() => {
        if (Meteor.userId()) {
          const indexes = Meteor.user().profile.propA;
          if (!indexes || indexes.length <= 0) return;
          dict.set('myStuff', indexes);
          console.log('auto has run');
        }
      });
    },
```

on the mongodb terminal:

```js
db.users.update({'_id':'123abc'}, {$set: {'profile.propB':'B'}})
```

triggers the autorun. even though the reactive data source is `Meteor.user().profile.propA;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mongo.Collection.findOne](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne) allows you to specify which fields are retrieved from the local database using the `fields` option. Only changes to the fields specified there will trigger the autorun again.

Since `Meteor.user()` is just a shorthand for `Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId())`, you can do the following to get updates for `propA` only:

```
const indexes = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId(), {
  fields: {
    'profile.propA': 1
  }
});
```

Note that `indexes` will only contain `profile.propA` and the document's `_id`. If you need more data from the user document but still want to receive reactive updates separately, you have to fetch that data in a second `autorun`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I hadn't realized the tracker was smart enough to go down to the field level.